# Azure Event Grid Deployment Failure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-eventgrid

The azure event grid is to  capture  the VM Creation and  deletion within the subscription  and  with Event Hub as the EndPoint . But the  deployment is failing with following  error

The specified topic property does not match the expected topic from the event subscription scope.

Any thoughts ?  Thanks in advance

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
},
"variables": {
    "eventHubNamespace": "evtNameSpace",
    "eventHubName": "evtHub001"

},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
        "name": "[variables('eventHubNamespace')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard"
        },
        "properties": {
            "isAutoInflateEnabled": true,
            "maximumThroughputUnits": 7
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "type": "EventHubs",
                "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                "name": "[variables('eventHubName')]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubNamespace'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "messageRetentionInDays": 1,
                    "partitionCount": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "cyberarktest00001",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventHubs', variables('eventHubNamespace'), variables('eventHubName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "topic": "[subscription().id]",
            "destination": {
                "endpointType": "EventHub",
                "properties": {
                    "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', variables('eventHubNamespace'), variables('eventHubName'))]"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "subjectBeginsWith": "",
                "subjectEndsWith": "",
                "isSubjectCaseSensitive": false,
                "includedEventTypes": [
                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess",
                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess"
                ],
                "advancedFilters": [
                    {
                        "operatorType": "StringContains",
                        "key": "data.operationName",
                        "values": [
                            "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write",
                            "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine/delete"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "operatorType": "StringContains",
                        "key": "data.httpRequest.method",
                        "values": [
                            "PUT",
                            "PATCH"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "retryPolicy": {
                "maxDeliveryAttempts": 2,
                "eventTimeToLiveInMinutes": 120
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our local environment, Below observations are based on the analysis.

> The specified topic property does not match the expected topic from the event subscription scope.

As per the  [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/eventsubscriptions?tabs=json) , `"Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions` doesn't have any property like `topic`
that why you arm template deployment got failed with the error.

We have  removed the topic property under `eventsubscriptions` in your shared template & tried deploying those resource & it got succeeded.

Here is the output screenshot for reference :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply  . Its creating a eventhub and  Namespace but  failed to capture the  vm creation and  deletion  events  ? Any idea